# Unable to test iOS 10 (iphone 5) Simulator using XCode 9

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode9

I've made my Deployment Target iOS 10.0, using Swift 4.

I've installed the Simulator for iOS 10, even iOS 9.3.

[image]

I can see it in the list Window > "Devices and Simulators"

[image]

And yet the simulator for iOS 10 (iphone 5) does not show in my dropdown option list for run-able simulators.

[image]

I'm guessing I'm overseeing something obvious?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Go here Window > "Devices and Simulators" on the left side you can see the list of available devices. There is a "+" button at the bottom. Tap on that and add iPhone 5 with iOS 10.0

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it, and I'm embarrassed to say how: I just restarted my computer, and bam iPhone 5 was in the list.

Comment: I guess only Xcode restart would have worked :D

Comment: No, that I tried like 10 times.. I don't know why.

Comment: robinyapockets, I tried restarting but still don't see iPhone5 option.  otherwise, my case appears exactly likes yours.  have you learned any more since then?  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The filtering that is done is based on deployment target.  Check the build settings of all targets in your project to see if you are overriding the project-level deployment target with a target-level deployment target.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't add another simulator (like iPhone 5) by clicking "+" icon in the bottom left corner of "Add simulators..." window, you should install iOS 10.0 (1.9GB) so that the old device can be run.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add simulator from simulators by clicking + icon the bottom right of the simulator list. Then it will show in the simulators list in the Xcode.

Answer (score -2):

At xCode:

1. click on project name.
2. select your target.
3. tap on General tab.
4. check your Deployment Target, and select 10.0.

now the iPhone 5s(10.0) should be shown in drop down list

Comment: The question explicitly asks about iPhone 5, _not_ iPhone 5s